# Writing an NPM Module: Require own package as dependency

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm creating a new NPM package. Within the repo, there's an `examples` directory with some javascript that gets compiled and served when running locally (or, eventually via github.io).

The setup is similar to [react-menu](https://github.com/react-component/menu). If you look inside any of the javascript files in that examples directory, you'll see that they require the package as if it had just been installed with `npm install react-menu`:

```
import Menu, { SubMenu, Item as MenuItem } from 'rc-menu';
```

But, it's not listed in any of the dependencies in package.json.

I know I can require my own module with something like `import myThing from '../../../index.js'`, but I'd rather not need to worry about all of the relative directories. I tried `import myThing from 'my-thing'`, but it of course couldn't find the package, and failed.

How is react-menu doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I should have looked a little deeper into the webpack docs.

tl;dr - The solution is [resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) configuration.

My directories are structured like this:

```
.
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── examples
│   ├── bundle.js
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── server.js
│   └── src
│       ├── components
│       │   ├── App.js
│       │   └── examples
│       │       └── ExampleOne.js
│       └── index.js
├── index.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── index.js
├── test
├── webpack.config.js
└── webpack.examples.config.js
```

Just adding **resolve** configuration to my **webpack.config.examples.js** did the trick. Here's the whole file, just for reference:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000',
        './examples/src/index.js',
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'examples'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.js.map',
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'my-package': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        },
    },

    devtool: 'eval-source-map',

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

So now, when I am working anywhere within the examples app, I can just use:

```
import myThing from 'my-package'
```